# Excel Delimiting cells?

Tags: excel

Say I have a cell that contains the data:

My Excel Data

How do I split/delimit this cell to have two separate cells:
My Excel
and
Data

Basically, I want to delimit on the first space from the right.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=excel+split+on+spaces&oq=excel+split+on+spaces&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3930j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=excel+split+last+word https://www.exceltip.com/excel-text/extract-the-last-word-in-a-cell-in-microsoft-excel.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","}}}",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))-1)
```

Then using that to find the second part:

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,B1,""))
```

[image]

---

Or reverse the order and find the last word first:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),999))
```

And for the first part:

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,C1,""))
```